# What value to use to clear out different data types?

Tags: javascript

Say you have a property that has a value and you want to clear out that value.  Do you always want to set it to null or undefined, or does the data type matter.

The only reason I could think that the data type would matter would be for documentation purpose of what this property's data type should be.

Example of what I am talking about:

```
var x = "string";
x = ""; // clear the value with the implied data type
// or
x = null; /* or */ x = undefined;
```

Same could be applied to Numbers(NaN), Arrays([]), Objects({}) where it would be cleared with the empty datatype equivalent.

I am mostly looking for what the best practice would be and why, not what is possible.

Comment: In most cases, the best practice would be to not reuse a variable, but instantiate a new one.

Comment: I typically use `null` to indicate that the value is unknown. `undefined` should be reserved for exactly that - the variable is not defined.

Comment: @JohnFx, the property still holds the same type of data, it's just that the value is now nothing.  I'm not trying to repurpose the property.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you want to accomplish.
If you want to remove the value I would set it to `null`.
If you want to give the string the empty string value do it.

`undefined` is undefined... I don't think manually changing a variable to undefined makes too much sense as it was defined...

And one last thing, the type doesn't matter, there is no problem changing a variable type in js, it's dynamic typing language.

Comment: I understand that it isn't a problem, but if you change the datatype of the variable then anyone relying on it to be of the initial data type might have unexpected results.

Comment: @asawilliams, so why would you change the value\type if something relies on it?